# multiple selection in drop down list in span tag

Tags: jquery, html, jsp

my requirement is print the multiple selection data in dropdown list. i tried this but it doesn't work. i dont know where i miss the logic. please correct me. here my code

```
    function getState() {
                ................
        document.getElementById('statediv').innerHTML=http.responseText;                        
                        http.send(params);

}
```

within body

```
    <div>   
        <h1 class="float-left">Create Annual Reports</h1>
        <div class="clear"></div>           
    </div>  
    <form  method="post" target="_blank"   action="<?=base_url();?>reports/prepareannualreport"  onsubmit="return fnValidate();" >
    <div id="registerform"> 
        <p></p> 
        <span class="float-left">State</span>
        <span id="statediv"><select name="multiple" id="multiple" multiple="multiple"><option value="0">(Select)</option></select>
</span>
```

In the dropdown list data successfully displayed. now when i choose multiple data in dropdown i want to print those values so i used the following function to print.

```
<script>
    function displayVals() {
      var singleValues = $("#single").val();
      var multipleValues = $("#multiple").val() || [];
      $("p").html(" <b>Multiple:</b> " + 
                  multipleValues.join(", "));
    }

    $("select").change(displayVals);
    displayVals();

</script>
```

if i replace body content with the following functions it prints the selected data in dropdown.

```
<select id="multiple" multiple="multiple">
    <option selected="selected">Multiple</option>
    <option>Multiple2</option>
    <option selected="selected">Multiple3</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("select").live('click', function(){
    if($("option").is(":selected")) {
        $("p").append("Option Selected"+$(this).val()+"<br />")
    }
});

<select id="multiple" multiple="multiple">
    <option selected="selected">Multiple</option>
    <option>Multiple2</option>
    <option selected="selected">Multiple3</option>
  </select>

<p></p>
```

Working Jfiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/xNmX2/

Comment: @John :Thanks your code works perfectly .but it is not working when i need to load the data in dropdown dynamically.

Comment: When you add dynamic select box you must ensure you use the LIVE handler, OR make a function and call it with the listener code, so i will update my example to use the live listener. You can only use $("element").click();... on elements that were loaded at page load, hence the reason for document.ready

Comment: also works with the change handler: $("select").live('change', function(){

Comment: @John: Thanks The code $("select").live('change', function(){   works fine. Thanks very much

Comment: @John : Why it is not working with $("select").click(function(){.

Comment: the reason you are using a live listener is because AFTER page load you are adding the select element to the memory of the web browser, LIVE searches the active memory including the active document. its the difference between dynamic and static elements from page load.

Comment: @John Thanks I am from IPhone game Development. That's why it takes time to understand and this is my first Project in webdesigning

Comment: @john : Hi i am struggle with dropdown function. if there was two drop down list in my page but i have apply the multiselect for one drop down only. how to differentiate two drop down list within this function $("select").live('click', function(){
    if($("option").is(":selected")) {
        $("p").append("Option Selected"+$(this).val()+"<br />")
    }
}); your code works for two drop down list. i need it works only for one please give a solution

Comment: @john : i got it just used class to difference drop down where id is not working .

Comment: well done, sorry I did not see your comment earlier I am super bussy at work... :(

Answer (score 0):

http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/select/#
I use this plugin to manage the selects :)
it's work perfectly..

Comment: thanks for the link and immediate response. why my code is not working . when i use the span tag with id it doesn't work. i want to know the reason please.